# Min \ Max form Input Validator Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, max, min

I try to limit the years input to 0-24 but everything i did didn't work. anyone has an idea?
relevant code from form.html :

```
<mat-card>
    <h1>Add Customer</h1>
    <form #customerForm="ngForm">
        <mat-form-field>
                <input 
                    matInput placeholder="Education years"
                    [(ngModel)] = "years"
                    name = "years"
                    min = "0"
                    max = "24"
                    required="required">
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    </mat-card>
```

relevant code from form.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../interfaces/customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'customerform',
  templateUrl: './customer-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-form.component.css']
})
export class CustomerFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() years: number;
  @Input() income: number;
  @Input() id: string;
```

Comment: Min and max only work on input type=“number”

Comment: @MikeOne I added type = "number" and the input in form.ts is number but still doesn't work..

Comment: Hmm.. can try to use [min]= and [max]=

Comment: Btw.. none of this will actually prevent a use from adding a higher number.. it just means that the form will become invalid..

Comment: @MikeOne so the data will add to the table anyway?

Comment: Yes. You should really consider using a reactive form where you have a lot more control over your inputs.

Comment: @MikeOne I tried this https://mdbootstrap.com/legacy/angular/6.1.1/?page=forms/input-validation
but nothing work for me..

Comment: Validation does not mean you cannot enter a value..

Comment: If you are binding with ngModel you could try using a getter and setter for the years property then limit the value in the setter. Or use a FormControl and subscribe to valueChanges, you can then limit the value in valueChanges.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: add an event and take care of calculating there. You can use blur event

```
// In HTML
<mat-card>
    <h1>Add Customer</h1>
    <form #customerForm="ngForm">
        <mat-form-field>
                <input 
                    matInput placeholder="Education years"
                    [(ngModel)] = "years"
                    name = "years"
                    (blur)="blurEvent($event)   // Add this event in HTML
                    required="required">

                // Add a small tag, add styles to make the text color red
                <small *ngIf="blurEventError" style="'color': red">
                     Value should be between 0 and 24
                 </small>

        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    </mat-card>

// In component.ts file

blurEventError: boolean = false;

blurEvent(event) {
  if (event && event.target.value) {
     if (
         customerForm.controls.years.value < 0 ||
         customerForm.controls.years.value > 24
     ) {
         this.blurEventError = true;
     } 
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can add a keypress / keyup / keydown events and it will work beautifully!